# Trying to convert selected date from mui-datepicker

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Im using the latest version of the datepicker with DayJS

When the data gets selected i still get as a response:
Date Wed Mar 01 2023 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)

I tried to Adjust this with the following code. But it doesnt seem to work.
Tried all sort of variations and i am new to mui. Anyone could share a light ?

```
<DatePicker label='Start Date' value={startDate} onChange={(newValue) => setStartDate(dayjs(startDate).format('YYYY/MM/DD'))} />
<DatePicker label='End Date' value={endDate} onChange={(newValue) => setEndDate(dayjs(startDate).format('YYYY/MM/DD'))}/>
```

Normal code returning the full date + Time

```
import { AdapterDayjs } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDayjs';
import { LocalizationProvider } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/LocalizationProvider';
import dayjs from 'dayjs';
import { DatePicker } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/DatePicker';

const [startDate , setStartDate ] = useState(null);
const [endDate , setEndDate ] = useState(null);     
<DatePicker label='Start Date' value={startDate} onChange={(newValue) => setStartDate(newValue)} />
<DatePicker label='End Date' value={endDate} onChange={(newValue) => setEndDate(newValue)}/>
```

Comment: What do you want as the outcome?

Answer (score 0):

Needed to look further.
I just needed to format the date into another const and send that to my function that needs the good format

```
const formattedStartDate = (dayjs(startDate).format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss'))
const formattedEndDate = (dayjs(endDate).format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss'))
```